# How to restart the ViewController with NavigationController previous configuration?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

I am learning iOS development and I am writing an app with login/sign-up navigation flow and the `TabBarViewController` with 3 `NavigationControllers`: Home, List and Profile.

[image: Storyboard]

On the Profile screen inside the `TabBarViewController` I have a Logout button, which deleted the session and I want to show the initial Startup screen (with BTC logo).
I do it with the following:

```
fileprivate func navigateToStartupScreen() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartupVC") as! StartupViewController
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        navigationController?.viewControllers = [vc]
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        view.window?.rootViewController = vc
        view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

}
```

The screen is displayed but its navigation pattern is broken. During a fresh install, the Login/Sign-up screens are displayed in `Show` mode with the Back button in the Toolbar. However, after the logout, these screens are displayed as `Modally` without the Back button.

How to reset the StartUp screen with the initial `NavigationController` configuration?

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eOFTzfwR1iFlt3mMxgH7QJYtm6lIoX9Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You have set the window's root view controller to your startup view controller, which has removed the navigation controller. Don't do that.  Remove the last two lines in your code block.  You also don't need the `popToRootViewController` if you are going to set the `viewControllers` array

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks so much!! This worked! So, setting the `rootViewController` on `window` is a bad practice? What is I want to skip the Login/Sign-up flow if I am logged in? I was setting the `TabBarController` as the root. Is it a mistake?

Comment: It's not a bad practice per se, but it is if you want to keep the existing root view controller (Your navigation controller in this case).  If you have previously removed the navigation controller as the root view controller and replaced it with the tab bar controller then you would need to create a new navigation controller and install it as the root view controller

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Paulw11 explanation, I found a working solution:

```
fileprivate func navigateToStartupScreen() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartupVC") as! StartupViewController
        navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
        let newNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        view.window?.rootViewController = newNavController
}
```